# How do I eliminate conditional from code?

Tags: java

How do I eliminate the ternary operator from the code below? I'm looking for something using only integer operators (shifts, additions, etc).

```
a = (a < 0) ? (-a * 2) - 1 : (a * 2)
```

Comment: For fun! I knew that it could be done in C easily, but I was curios how to do it in Java.

Comment: Doing this in Java is much the same as doing this in C. After all Java is based on C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Off the top of my head, assuming `a` is an `int`:

```
a = 2*a*(1+2*(a>>31)) - (a>>>31);
```

`>>` is arithmetic (signed) shift left. So `a>>31` replaces all the bits with the sign bit. All bits set gives -1. Multiple by two and add one, negatives go to -1 and positives (and zero) to 1.

`>>>` is logical (unsigned) shift left. So `a>>>31` clears the top 31 bits and places the sign bit in bit 0 (0 for positive numbers and zero; 1 for negative numbers).

The "proper" way of doing something vaguely like this is:

```
a ^= a>>31;
a *= 2;
```

Comment: I was going to say "And that's better *how?!* " but the OP didn't ask for *better*, the OP asked for getting rid of the ternary. Well, this does that...and demonstrates why "why?" is the relevant question. :-) That said, it doesn't work. (a = 3 => 0, which is clearly wrong)

Comment: @John: doesn't matter. I changed the sign in the example.

Comment: @John: Nope, that doesn't fix it either.

Comment: I'm getting myself confused here. Years since a pissed about in assembly language.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why.

Comment: @Tom: the last version works perfectly and is even faster then the ternary operator.

Comment: @Tom: Your "proper" way gives the wrong result for `a = -3`. But the edited version at the top works for that case (haven't tested others).

Comment: @Alexandru I doubt it's faster than the ternary operation, especially when taking HotSpot optimizations into account.

Comment: @Jorn I wouldn't guarantee it. I believe unpredictable branches can be expensive, while arithmetical operations are not. Some instruction sets (like 32-bit ARM) will be able to avoid the branches. However, most of the cycles are likely to be eaten up elsewhere.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it looks like the first version does [a<0] => `a=a*6+1`, [a>=0] => `a=2*a`, while the second version does [a(odd)<0] => `a=(a-1)*2`, [a(even)<0] => `a=(a+1)*2`, [a>=0] => `a=a*2`.

Comment: @Jeffrey For `a<0`, `a>>31` is `-1` and `a>>>31` is `1`, so `2*a*(1-2) - 1`. Second one needs to add or subtract the original sign bit (`a>>>31`), but I quite like it written as multiple statements, but that loses the original value - undecided how to rewrite it.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline - OK. I had the shift operators backward then.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is several answers demonstrating that getting rid of the ternary is not a good idea. It means your code is hard to read, hard to debug, hard to maintain. You haven't flagged this as homework or an intellectual exercise, and so the right answer is: **Don't.** Leave the ternary in place. It's clear, it's expressive, and it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (a < 0) 
  a = (-a * 2) - 1 
else 
  a = (a * 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
a= (2 * Math.abs(a)) - (a >>> 31);
```

Comment: Nope. `a = -3` => `7` when it should be `5`.

Comment: Technically abs() uses a condition in Java.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
a = ((a ^ (a >> 31)) + 1) * 2 - ~(a >>> 31) - 1;
```

(I haven’t actually tried it, though—not being a Java programmer.)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler answer is to use

```
(a ^ a >> 31) * 2 + (a >>> 31)
```